# Why a String variable can not be assigned to another string variable in C?

Tags: c, string, pointers

Why in the below written code we can not assign `strA` to `strB` and as the pointer `pA` holds address of pointer `pB` then address should have been copied on assignment of `pA` to `pB` and `strB` should have contain the value same as `strB`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
char strA[80] = "A string to be used for demonstration purposes";
char strB[80];
int main(void)
{
    char *pA; /* a pointer to type character */
    char *pB; /* another pointer to type character */
    puts(strA); /* show string A */
    pA = strA; /* point pA at string A */
    puts(pA); /* show what pA is pointing to */
    pB = strB; /* point pB at string B */
    putchar('\n'); /* move down one line on the screen */
    pB=pA;
    strB=strA;
    puts(strB); /* show strB on screen */
    puts(strA);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Changed the tag from C++ to C, as it seems you are specifically asking a C question.

Comment: Is this [homework](http://pet.ece.iisc.ernet.in/gautham/ctut/ch3.html)?

Comment: `strA` and `strB` aren't string variables. there is no such thing as `string variable` in C. they are arrays. an array can't be assigned to another array.

Comment: Your question is a FAQ, http://c-faq.com/charstring/assign.html, voting to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write:

char strB[80];

strB is not a pointer but a constant pointer. It means that you can't change the address pointed by strB, and thus

strB=strA;

won't do anything.

Answer (score 4):

You can't assign arrays in C (`strB=strA`). You must use `strcpy` or `memcpy` to transfer contents of one array/pointer to an array.